# A variable is being overwritten for no apparent reason

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am writing a scheduler in C, and in order to print it I have prepared a function that prints a table with names and times of "events". 
In order to print the tables I have a separation after each line, which is basically "|=======|========|=======|.....", so I saved it in a variable and tried using it to print. And for some reason I overflow it with values.

I tried finding out where the error is, and I've tried decreasing the amount of characters added to a string that is defined after it(to prevent the overflow), but those didn't work

```
char line_break[] = "|====================|====================|====================|====================|====================|====================|====================|";
printf("\n|       Sunday       |       Monday       |       Teusday      |      Wedensday     |      Thursday      |       Friday       |      Saturday      |\n%s\n",line_break);

for (int i=0; i < max(schedule_index);i++) {
    char events[8+EVENT_NAME_SIZE*7] = {0};
    char  hours[8+EVENT_NAME_SIZE*7] = {0};
    strcat(events, "|");
    strcat(hours,  "|");
    for (int day=0; day < DAYS_PER_WEEK; day++) {
        char temp_events[EVENT_NAME_SIZE]= {0};
        char temp_hours[EVENT_NAME_SIZE] = {0};
        for (int i=0; i<EVENT_NAME_SIZE;i++) {
            temp_events[i] = ' ';
            temp_hours[i] = 'b';
        }

        strcat(events, temp_events);
        strcat(events, "|");

        strcat(hours, temp_hours);
        strcat(hours, "|");
    }

    printf("%s\n", events);
    printf("%s\n", hours);
    printf("%s\n", line_break);
}
```

Whenever I execute the code I get the following:

```
|       Sunday       |       Monday       |       Teusday      |      Wedensday     |      Thursday      |       Friday       |      Saturday      |
|====================|====================|====================|====================|====================|====================|====================|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |
|                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |                    |
|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|
```

So that's how I figured out the problem is the `line_break` variable is being overridden by the `hours` variable but I still have no clue as to why it's happening. `EVENT_NAME_SIZE` is declared to be 20,`DAYS_PER_WEEK` is also 7, `max(schedule_index)` is just for me to find out what is the max amount of hours I have to draw,

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to debug a program with a proper debugger.  Not sure what your development platform is.  Load the program in a debugger, step through each line of code, and examine the variable values.

Comment: May I request that the indentation on the code formatting be made a bit more regular?

Comment: You fill up your arrays `temp_hours` and `temp_events` without adding a terminating `\0`. When you pass them to `strcat` which expects to get pointers to C strings, i.e. NUL-terminated character sequences you invoke undefined behaviour

Comment: As Gerhardh said... you probably want to `char temp_hours[EVENT_NAME_SIZE + 1]` (add a space the the null termination) otherwise strcat will keep cat'ting until it finds a null. There may be a few other places where a +1 is needed

Comment: @Gerhardh might be a good answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: If you use Clang or GCC, you can very very easily identify the cause of these errors by adding `-fsanitize=address` to your compiler invocation. The program will stop cleanly at the point of overflow.

Comment: Absent a compiler bug, a variable is never overwritten for no apparent reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your array declarations exclude space for string terminating zero byte.

It should be:

```
char events[8+EVENT_NAME_SIZE*7+1] = {0};
char  hours[8+EVENT_NAME_SIZE*7+1] = {0};
```

where you want to hold `EVENT_NAME_SIZE` spaces or `b` characters and 8 `|` characters.

and:

```
    char temp_events[EVENT_NAME_SIZE+1]= {0};
    char temp_hours[EVENT_NAME_SIZE+1] = {0};
```

If you want to store `EVENT_NAME_SIZE` characters in a string, you need `EVENT_NAME_SIZE` bytes of space plus one byte for terminating zero character.

Functions like `strcat` need zero terminated arrays. Also programmer need to make sure the destination have enough space available. The behavior of the first `strcat(events, temp_events);` is undefined - `temp_events` is not null terminated, so `strcat` was accessing some random data of memory.